# Rendering TextFeild issue flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an issue fixing Redering issue while creating TextFeild in dart.

From a short search i found out that it is better putting the above widget in a Container though it did not helped fixing the issue.

I'm having an issue fixing Redering issue while creating TextFeild in dart.

From a short search i found out that it is better putting the above widget in a Container though it did not helped fixing the issue.

main  screen class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notifier_demo/components/TextFieldComp.dart';
import 'package:notifier_demo/models/user.dart';
import 'package:notifier_demo/notifier/UserNotifier.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

    class HomeMaterialScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeMaterialScreenState createState() => _HomeMaterialScreenState();
    }

    class _HomeMaterialScreenState extends State<HomeMaterialScreen> {
      final _user = new User();
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        UserNotifier userNotifier= Provider.of<UserNotifier>(context);

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Profile'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 16),
            child: Builder(
                builder: (context) => Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                             child:TextFieldComp(_user),

                            ),

                            Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 20),
                            ),
                            SwitchListTile(
                              title: const Text('Monthly newsletter'),
                              value: _user.newsletter,
                              onChanged: (bool val) =>
                                  setState(() => _user.newsletter = val),
                            ),
                            CheckboxListTile(
                              title: const Text('Coocking'),
                              value: _user.passions[User.PassionCooking],
                              onChanged: (val) => setState(
                                      () => _user.passions[User.PassionCooking] = val),
                            ),
                            CheckboxListTile(
                                title: const Text('Hiking'),
                                value: _user.passions[User.PassionHiking],
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    userNotifier.addUser(_user);
                                    _user.passions[User.PassionHiking] = val;
                                  });
                                }
                            ),


                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 16, horizontal: 16),
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  final form = _formKey.currentState;
                                  if (form.validate()) {
                                    form.save();
                                    _user.save();
                                    _showDialog(context);
                                  }
                                },
                              )
                          ),

                          SizedBox(

                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index)=>Text('PlaceHolder for List'),
                                itemCount: userNotifier.userList.length,
                              )
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))),
          ),
        );
      }

      _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Submitting Form'),
        ));
      }
    }
```

the TextFeild class:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notifier_demo/models/user.dart';

class TextFieldComp extends StatefulWidget{
  User _user;
  TextFieldComp(User user) {
    _user=user;

  }

  @override
  _TextFieldCompState createState() => _TextFieldCompState();
}

class _TextFieldCompState extends State<TextFieldComp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child:    TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty)
                  return "Please insert Value";
                else
                  return null;
              },
              onSaved: (val) =>
                  setState(() => widget._user.firstName = val)
          )
        ),
        Container(
                 child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last Name'),
            validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty)
            return "Please insert Value";
            else
            return null;
            },
            onSaved: (val) =>
            setState(() => widget._user.lastName = val)

    ),
        ),


      ],
    );


  }
}
```

Log:

```
I/flutter ( 9200): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9200): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 9200): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter ( 9200): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter ( 9200): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter ( 9200): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter ( 9200): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter ( 9200): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter ( 9200): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
I/flutter ( 9200): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
I/flutter ( 9200): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
I/flutter ( 9200): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
I/flutter ( 9200): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
I/flutter ( 9200): constraints provided by the parent.
I/flutter ( 9200): If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
I/flutter ( 9200):   https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
I/flutter ( 9200):   http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
I/flutter ( 9200): The affected RenderFlex is:
I/flutter ( 9200):   RenderFlex#6a02e relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#30dc5] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#7b5bd] ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2b979] ← ⋯, parentData: <none> (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=422.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: MISSING, direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: stretch, verticalDirection: down)
I/flutter ( 9200): The creator information is set to:
I/flutter ( 9200):   Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#30dc5] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ←
I/flutter ( 9200):   Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 9200):   RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#7b5bd] ← _PointerListener ← Listener
I/flutter ( 9200):   ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2b979] ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 9200): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#e33e5 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter ( 9200):   needs compositing
I/flutter ( 9200):   creator: _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#30dc5] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ←
I/flutter ( 9200):     Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 9200):     RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#7b5bd] ← _PointerListener ← Listener
I/flutter ( 9200):     ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2b979] ← RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 9200):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter ( 9200):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=422.7, 0.0<=h<=749.5)
I/flutter ( 9200):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 9200): See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
I/flutter ( 9200): If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:
I/flutter ( 9200):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 9200): 
I/flutter ( 9200): User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 9200):   SingleChildScrollView
I/flutter ( 9200):   file:///C:/Users/omer/AndroidStudioProjects/clima_flutter_app/notifier_demo/lib/screens/home_material_screen.dart:28:24
I/flutter ( 9200): 
I/flutter ( 9200): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 9200): #0      RenderFlex.performLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:691:11)
I/flutter ( 9200): #1      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:718:10)
I/flutter ( 9200): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #3      _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:497:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #23     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:206:11)
I/flutter ( 9200): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #25     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter ( 9200): #26     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:444:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #27     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #28     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter ( 9200): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #33     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1232:11)
I/flutter ( 9200): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #47     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #49     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #50     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3140:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #52     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter ( 9200): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #56     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #62     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #66     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:152:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #67     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1578:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #68     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
I/flutter ( 9200): #69     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:341:19)
I/flutter ( 9200): #70     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:761:13)
I/flutter ( 9200): #71     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:280:5)
I/flutter ( 9200): #72     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
I/flutter ( 9200): #73     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:975:9)
I/flutter ( 9200): #74     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:784:7)
I/flutter ( 9200): #83     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter ( 9200): #84     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter ( 9200): #85     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
I/flutter ( 9200): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 9200): 
I/flutter ( 9200): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFlex#6a02e relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter ( 9200):   creator: Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#30dc5] ← Semantics ←
I/flutter ( 9200):     _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 9200):     RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#7b5bd] ← _PointerListener ← Listener
I/flutter ( 9200):     ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2b979] ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 9200):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter ( 9200):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=422.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 9200):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 9200):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 9200):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 9200):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 9200):   crossAxisAlignment: stretch
I/flutter ( 9200):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 9200): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter ( 9200):     child 1: RenderFlex#e703f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):       child 1: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#65551 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):         child: RenderMouseRegion#4ff1d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):           child: RenderIgnorePointer#2bb3e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):             child: RenderPointerListener#20294 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):       child 2: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#06bc1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):         child: RenderMouseRegion#57aa7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):           child: RenderIgnorePointer#7eca8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):             child: RenderPointerListener#fa0bd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):     child 2: RenderPadding#7190e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):       child: RenderLimitedBox#1277a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):         child: RenderConstrainedBox#e1fb0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 9200):     child 3: RenderMergeSemantics#583ac NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):       child: RenderMouseRegion#545d8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):         child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#93036 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):           child: RenderPointerListener#56f31 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):             child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#13b79 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):     child 4: RenderMergeSemantics#43d98 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):       child: RenderMouseRegion#75318 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):         child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#0566c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):           child: RenderPointerListener#a678e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):             child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#b65af NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):     child 5: RenderMergeSemantics#1223e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):       child: RenderMouseRegion#99b6f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):         child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#cb1e4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):           child: RenderPointerListener#5cb96 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200):             child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#d0902 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9200): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Wrap `ListView.builder` inside `Expanded` widget instead of `SizedBox`

Comment: @AyushBherwani didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In `Scaffold` and `TextFieldComp` use `Flexible` and use `Expanded flex` to control others

code snippet

```
return Container(     
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
              child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
```

working demo

[image]

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeMaterialScreen(),
    );
  }
}



class HomeMaterialScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeMaterialScreenState createState() => _HomeMaterialScreenState();
}

class _HomeMaterialScreenState extends State<HomeMaterialScreen> {
  User _user;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<User> userList = [
    User(firstName: "abc", lastName: "def", newsletter: true),
    User(firstName: "123", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "1", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "2", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "3", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "4", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "5", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "6", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "1a", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "2a", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "3a", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "4a", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "5a", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
    User(firstName: "6a", lastName: "456", newsletter: false),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _user = new User(newsletter: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //UserNotifier userNotifier= Provider.of<UserNotifier>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 16),
        child: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Flexible(child: TextFieldComp(_user)),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 20),
                        ),
                       SwitchListTile(
                          title: const Text('Monthly newsletter'),
                          value: false,
                          onChanged: (bool val) =>
                              setState(() => _user.newsletter = val),
                        ),
                        CheckboxListTile(
                          title: const Text('Coocking'),
                          value: false,
                         /* onChanged: (val) => setState(
                                  () => _user.passions[User.PassionCooking] = val),*/
                        ),
                        CheckboxListTile(
                            title: const Text('Hiking'),
                            value: true,
                            /*onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                userNotifier.addUser(_user);
                                _user.passions[User.PassionHiking] = val;
                              });
                            }*/
                        ),

                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 16, horizontal: 16),
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  final form = _formKey.currentState;
                                  if (form.validate()) {
                                    form.save();
                                    //_user.save();
                                    _showDialog(context);
                                  }
                                },
                              )),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                              Text(' ${userList[index].firstName}'),
                          itemCount: userList.length,
                        )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ))),
      ),
    );
  }

  _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text('Submitting Form'),
    ));
  }
}

class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  bool newsletter;

  User({
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.newsletter,
  });
}

class TextFieldComp extends StatefulWidget {
  User _user;
  TextFieldComp(User user) {
    _user = user;
  }

  @override
  _TextFieldCompState createState() => _TextFieldCompState();
}

class _TextFieldCompState extends State<TextFieldComp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      //height: 200,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
              child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty)
                      return "Please insert Value";
                    else
                      return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (val) =>
                      setState(() => widget._user.firstName = val))),
          Flexible(
            child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last Name'),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty)
                    return "Please insert Value";
                  else
                    return null;
                },
                onSaved: (val) => setState(() => widget._user.lastName = val)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey,first of all thanks. I'm wondering which app you used to record the demo.Moreover,I was reading your comment about using the flutter run and pressing r when it says "Invoke hot reload" but i didnt see any blue tool bar and i didn't understand what zero counter are you talking about.I'm also wondering how you figure it out what is the problem because by looking at the terminal i barely understood a thing.I think it's crucial for my learning process and i would appreciate an explanation

Comment: comment is from flutter default project. I did not remove default comment. sorry.

Comment: clue came from error message. "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height" and  log also suggest "using Flexible". they all lead to some point. flutter do not know how to draw your layout. It did not know height of your component. I just check every component and remark / unremark to see error disappear or not.